# How do I preserve the information keyed in by the user in Django form fields when the submission fails validation while using a CSS customized form?

Tags: django, django-forms

1. I understand that you need to pass the `form` from views.py into the template in order for this to happen. I'm already using, in views.py for the view handling the form:

   > ```
   > if request.method == 'POST':
   >     stuff
   > else:
   >     form = MyForm()
   > ```
2. But I also want to customize the look of my form using CSS, so instead of using `{{ form.as_p }}` or similar, the form in my template looks like this (posting just the name field and submit button to keep it short):

   > ```
   > <div class="fieldWrapper">
   >     <label class="field" for="id_name">Name*:</label>
   >     {{ form.name.errors }}
   >     <input class="box" type="text" name="name" id="id_name" maxlength="100"/>
   > </div>
   >
   > <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Submit" />
   > ```

   - Using the suggested `{{ form.name }}` followed by `#id_name{ css stuff }` or `.fieldwrapper input{ css stuff}` (each field has a fieldwrapper div around it) in the template does not seem to work, even though I have verified that `{{ form.name }}` does indeed have `id="id_name"` in my browser.

I really don't have any leads as to what approach should I take in solving this. For now, my users face issues of having to repopulate the entire form from scratch if they submit a form that fails validation.

I am using Django 1.3.7; Python 2.7 on PythonAnywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `{{form.name.value}}`, and it will repopulate the value entered for a particular field when an invalid form is redisplayed.

```
<input class="box" type="text" name="name" id="id_name" maxlength="100" value="{{form.name.value}}"/>
```

Comment: Quick and easy way to solve my problem, thanks! For others, just note that {{ form.name.value }} defaults to None, so one would have to use value="{% if form.name.value %}{{ form.name.value }}{% endif %}" so that you don't get None when the user first sees the form.